# Please help - SQL Join query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a project, and need to join results from 2 tables into one set.
The tables are ordered as such:

```
gameData: [Id,TeamID, data..........]

players: [Id (same as above), name, data.....]
```

I need to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM gameData and SELECT data FROM players WHERE gameData.Id = players.Id
```

And here is what I have thusfar.

```
SELECT * FROM gameData AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN players AS B on A.playerID = B.Id;
```

And have it return all of the values from A, and only the data from B.

I know that the syntax is not correct, I have little experience working with SQL Joins, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Trying both answers now. Thanks!

Edit2: Can I do something like: "Select a.* from tableA as a"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Select a.Id, a.TeamID, a.data, b.data
FROM gameData as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
players b On a.ID =  b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate the fields that you select and alias the tables, like:

```
select a.Id, a.TeamId, a.data, b.data 
from tableA a
join tableB b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I love you guys, working as intended now!

Thanks!

The query I ended up using was:

```
Select a.*, b.height, b.weight from gameData as a LEFT OUTER JOIN players b on a.playerID = b.Id;
```

Comment: Why did you accept the answer which used an inner join then?

Comment: The answers were edited, before the answers were pretty much identical, I accepted the one who commented first... Changing the selected answer now.